# Cannot add billing in Google Cloud.An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-3DSRFT-08]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I am trying to enable my google cloud billing and my card got amount deducted but the account didn't activate and even the page didn't refresh.

After the payment is done the payment window closes but nothing happens. I tried several times which deducted my amount many times but the same happens and now I get this error.

Please help.

Comment: Hi there! Have you tried to contact GCP Support? All customers, regardless of their support package, have access to Billing Support. You can contact them by chat and they can take a look on your account.

Comment: I tried contacting GCP support but couldn't .I was often redirected to their chat robot which couldn't solve my problem.Could you please share email address of GCP support team?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
I repeated all the steps on Firefox and it worked! Probably a cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your issue is related to the known issue with creating GCP billing accounts.

Please follow [this issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186210363) at the Google Public Issue Tracker to be updated. Feel free to add comments, CC yourself to receive emails with updates, and press `+1` to inform the GCP team that you're facing this issue.